# Oracle APEX Custom Authentication Scheme User Role

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, acl

So I followed the instruction from this blogpost:
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/custom-authentication-and-authorization-using-built-in-apex-access-control-a-how-to

to create a custom authentication/authorization scheme. So far the login works well, but I can't figure out how to give a user a certain role. I can add users to the table and they can login sucessfully. However, if I select a role and use the REPLACE_USER_ROLE API from apex, it uses the standard apex_appl_acl_users table instead of my custom users table.

Based on the blogpost, how can I assign user roles to my custom user accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse "authentication" and "authorization".

Authentication is about accessing an application. Authorization is about what a user can do in the application. Authorization is done by granting roles to a user in the app - I believe that is what your question is about.

There are 2 ways of controlling application authorization.

1. Define roles and user assignment in the "Application Access Control" shared component. This allows you to use the `APEX_ACL` API. This is what is described in the blog you mention
2. Define roles and assignments in your own tables. In that case you'll have to write your own pl/sql to manage role/user assignments. Sounds like this is what you want. You can create authorization schemes on top of your own tables

Comment: In best case, I want to use the APEX_ACL to assign the users in my custom users database roles. Is this possible? 
I mean in the blog he also used the API and changed the role of a user stored in the users database. So the API uses the custom DB instead of the internal one.

Comment: In the blog Doug uses APEX_APPL_ACL_ROLES - that is the internal table used by apex for roles and user assignment in the "Application Access Control" shared component. That is not a custom table. Either use the apex roles and assignments and benefit from API or do it all custom. There is no middle way

Comment: I thought the same, but he created a table users and inserted a user for which he later changed the role using the APEX_ACL API. So this seems like a middle way for me, where he uses a custom authentication scheme and the standard ACL API to give those users roles, no?

Comment: Ah I see the confusion. Don't confuse "authentication" and "authorization". In the blog the authentication is custom, the authorization is not. Both are completely separate.... the API can only be used if roles are defined in  in the "Application Access Control" shared component. It doesn't matter where users are defined